# TypeScript type definition for promise.prototype.finally

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, definitelytyped

I was using this ES6 Promise compatible finally implementation called [promise.prototype.finally](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/Promise.prototype.finally) in a Node application that I want to convert to TypeScript however there are no typing available for this package that I can find on [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/). In these situations I've written up my own impromptu type definitions for just the subset of functionality that I need but in this case it is a library that modifies the prototype of the Promise object and I haven't encountered any conventional way to represent this in TypeScript. Any ideas?

Possibly related:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/280
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7015
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6722
- [Declaration merging with ES6 style modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064734/declaration-merging-with-es6-style-modules)

Answer (score 15):

Whilst the answer from Slava is correct, it only deals with the typing of the `finally` block. To actually incorporate the shim into your code, so you can write `p.finally(() => { ... })`, you need to invoke the shim.

<strike>Unfortunately the [typings on DefinitelyTyped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/promise.prototype.finally) do not currently support the `shim` function so [until this is supported](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/13339), I'd advise to add the typings yourself.</strike>

```
declare interface Promise<T> {
  finally<U>(onFinally?: () => U | Promise<U>): Promise<U>;
}

declare module 'promise.prototype.finally' {
  export function shim(): void;
}
```

The types are now available. Install with

```
npm install --save-dev @types/promise.prototype.finally
```

In your TypeScript code, during application bootstrap, you can then call

```
import { shim } from 'promise.prototype.finally';
shim();
```

This will add the `finally` block to the `Promise` prototype, allowing you to use `finally` as required.

Comment: Uhm I can't get this working with Visual Studio Code 1.20 - It'll build but when running the code I'll get a "Cannot find module 'promise.prototype.finally'" error, altought the module is available in node_modules@types. Wonder if that's even worth investigating since https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20411 added native support for "finally", finally.

Comment: Just using `yarn add @types/promise.prototype.finally --dev` did it for me

Answer (score 11):

For anyone wondering how to get this working natively without any shims: as of TS 2.7 it's possible.

Note that TS 2.7 is not yet fully (26. Feb. 2018) ES2018 compatible. While there are still a few things [missing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20463), [Promise.finally made it into the 2.7 release](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20385). Also tsconfig-schema should already accept ES2018 as target but yet TS 2.7 has no knowledge of ES2018. For now to use the new features, such as Promise.finally, which already are in 2.7, **you'll have to use `"target": "ESNEXT"` in your tsconfig.json.**

Then you'll be able to write code like this:

```
myAsyncFunction().then
(
  (var) => console.log("executing then. " + var)
)
.catch
(
  (var) => console.log("executing catch. " + var)
)
.finally
(
  () => console.log("executing finally.")
)
```

Notice how [finally will not take any arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) due to it's nature.

**IMPORTANT**: while TS will transpile correctly and understand what you're doing you still have to check if your JS-Engine supports Promise.finally. In my case I was using NodeJs 8.x and of course the produced JS was not executable because **Promise.Finally is supported starting with <strike>in the latest NodeJs 10.x nightly builds</strike> Node 10.x (stable), [see this link](http://node.green/#ES2018).**

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own d.ts file and reference it in the tsconfig.json file.
Of you do it you can contribute to the DefinitelyTyped git for others like yourself

Update:

If I understood correctly what you mean you can extend the existing `Promise` class in your own d.ts file. Make the method to be optional so it won't tell you the actual `Promise` class is not implementing the interface correctly.
You need to extend it as an interface.

Your d.ts file should look like this

```
declare module 'es6-promise/dist/es6-promise' {
    export interface Promise <R> {
      finally?<U>(onFinally?: () => U | Promise<U>): Promise<U>;
    }
}
```

And it should work properly...

I created a project for you as an example:
[promise-extension-typescript-example](https://github.com/slavik57/promise-extension-typescript-example)

I created a pull request to the DefinitelyTyped git repository, hope it will be accepted and you can download it from there...

Comment: I'm definitely aware of these points. The situation I'm describing above is specific to that package where it is modifying an existing object/class instead of defining a new type or set of types.

Comment: I'm not sure about `Thenable` but I'm working with promises as defined in the ES6 polyfill `es6-promise` but _promise.prototype.finally_ is supposed to support any ES5 compatible promise implementation. The type I'm working with is Promise<any>. Substituting Thenable with Promise in your implementation above doesn't work for me because tsc gives me an error at the site of the import for the Promise polyfill `import { Promise } from 'es6-promise';`.

Comment: If you looke in the d.ts file [es6-promise](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts) you will see that `Promise` implements the `Thenable`. On the code I gave you I extend that interface with a new method

Comment: From what I can see as described above, extending an interface by writing a new interface with the same name doesn't appear to be compatible with the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: You can see it works file here: [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20A%7B%0A%09greet()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0A%09greet2()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20a%3A%20A%3B%0A%0Aa.greet()%3B%0Aa.greet2()%3B)

Comment: Seems to work there but I get an error "Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Thenable'
interface Thenable<T>" by importing via `import { Promise, Thenable } from 'es6-promise';` followed by the code block that you posted above. Perhaps only interfaces in the local module scope can be modified in this way?

Comment: Did you define the interface in another d.ts file and added it to the tsconfig.json or just added it to the ts file?

Comment: I added another d.ts file and it worked too well, it errored that the Promise is not implementing the interface correctly, I'll look into that

Comment: I updated the answer with making the method optional and putting the interface inside the module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105820/discussion-between-jpierson-and-slava-shp).

Comment: I think my edited answer should answer your question now