# Angular 5 - how to do something like a finally block?

Tags: angular, angular5, observable

I'm writing an app with Angular 5 and it's important for some features to have something like a finally block after my http calls.

I am not sure how to do this using Observables as there is no finally function in an Observable: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/index.html

```
code snippet:
getInfo() {

    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('username', 'swapp')
        .set('password', "test");

    return this.http
        .get('myurl', {params: params})
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a HttpClient interceptor? It centrally handles the logic before making the requests and after getting a response.

Comment: Because I want to control what happens each time. Some pages in my app will do different things than others.

Comment: It does have finally: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/finally.html
If you are using Rxjs6 then it will be `this.http.get('myurl', {params: params}).pipe(finally())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intercepter` for  that:

http_intercepter.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHeaders,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppService } from './../app.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';


@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private appService: AppService,
        ) {

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param req - parameter to handle http request
     * @param next - parameter for http handler
     */
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const started = Date.now();
        /**
         * Handle newly created request with updated header (if given)
         */
        return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            /**
             * Sucessfull Http Response Time.
             */
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
            }

        }, (err: any) => {
            /**
             * redirect to the error_handler route according to error status or error_code
             * or show a modal
             */
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                switch (err.status) {
                    case 400:
                        console.log("400 type")
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        console.log("401 type")
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        console.log("404 type");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: MyInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
    ]
```

Comment: But what if I want to control it for each http request? Sometimes I want to do something different each time.

Comment: In the context of the question, maybe add the `finally` method block (after the error block) to the .do() event?

Comment: you can do something like this for each request.
this.http
    .get('myurl', {params: params})
    .subscribe((resp: any)=>{console.log(resp);},(err)=>{console.log(err);});

Comment: but that will be handled in your component only. intercepter is  for centralised exceptions

Comment: Again, I want something identical to a finally block in a promise. I don't want to call the same code over again if there is a success or error.

Comment: do u want to do that think for all request??

Comment: if yes than put that common block in intercepter.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to add a finally block to an Observable.

import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';

```
    return this.http
        .get(CONSTANT.ENV.prod.url.concat(endpoint), {params: params})
        .catch(this.errorHandler)
        .finally(this.handleFinally)
```

Answer (score 0):

as @UnluckyAj says you can centralized your catch http failure in INTERCEPTORS or if you want to do granulary in every calls try smething like:

getInfo() {

```
const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('username', 'swapp')
    .set('password', "test");

return this.http
    .get('myurl', {params: params})
    .subscribe(this.onsuccessHandler,this.errorHandler); // FIRST function is for success SECOND for failure
```

}

If you want a Finally Block try:

```
return Observable.defer(() => {


    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('username', 'swapp')
        .set('password', "test");



       return this.http
            .get('myurl', {params: params})
            .subscribe(this.onsuccessHandler,this.errorHandler);
            .finally(() => {}               
            );
```

Comment: But I want something similar to a final block in a promise. Executed if it is successful or not.

Comment: @user1261710 it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48988130/6332074

Comment: so you are applying finally() on subscribe??